# C# What is the best practice to pass a parameter as method argument to both get AND set data from a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, method-parameters

I'm fairly new to extension methods and i was wanting to make something very generic to re-order any type of list of an Entity Framework DbSet<TEntity>. To do so, i'd need to precise what property the entity is using as it's "Order" field. The most elegant way that was working for me was by using the property name (string) as the argument to then use it to get the PropertyInfo.

```cs
public static void OrderList<TModel>(this List<TModel> list, string propertyName)
{
  PropertyInfo property = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(propertyName);
  list.OrderList(property);
}

public static void OrderList<TModel>(this List<TModel> list, PropertyInfo property)
{
  var order = (int)list.Min(x => property.GetValue(x));
  list.ForEach(x => { property.SetValue(x, order++); });
}

// Called this way:
myList.OrderList(nameof(Class.OrderProperty));
```

The thing is that i'm not much of a fan of the whole "nameof(Class.Property)"... Would there be a better way to do so? I tried to use `Func<TModel, int> property` because i REALLY like how you call these `list.function(x => x.Property)`, i really think it's the easiest one to understand. But I've come to learn that you can only get data from this, to set data i'd have to use an "*Action*" delegate to also set data, but then i'd have to enter the same property twice and it's not helping much... Only other option i can think of is using `System.Linq.Expressions` but i'm very unfamiliar with those and have no idea how to use them or even if it could solve my problem...

Hope this made sense and thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Have you considered using System.Linq for this where you can take `var myList = new List<TModel>()` and order it using `var mySortedList = myList.OrderBy(listitem=>listitem.Name)`. I'm thinking that the extension you're trying to write might already exist in Linq.  This is for example `class TModel{ public string Name { get; } public int ID { get; } }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @IVSoftware , but the way i named the functions might be confusing. It's not really about only sorting the list but changing the "Order" property from the TModel to then save the context...

Comment: I would use two parameters as you describe. A ```Func``` to retrieve the value and an ```Action``` to set it: ```OrderList<TModel, TProperty>(this List<TModel> list, Func<TModel, TProperty> propertyGetter, Action<TModel, TProperty> propertySetter)```. I find it a better practice to keep control over how the value is set outside of the function. If I were to see your method called "OrderList" with just one parameter, the last thing I would expect it to do is change the values of my properties. If I see the ```Action``` as well, it is clearer what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it with `Expression<T>`:

```
public static void OrderList<TModel>(this IList<TModel> list, Expression<Func<TModel, int>> propertyExpression) 
    where TModel : notnull
    => list.OrderList(propertyExpression, i => ++i);
public static void OrderList<TModel>(this IList<TModel> list, Expression<Func<TModel, uint>> propertyExpression) 
    where TModel : notnull
    => list.OrderList(propertyExpression, i => ++i);
public static void OrderList<TModel>(this IList<TModel> list, Expression<Func<TModel, long>> propertyExpression) 
    where TModel : notnull
    => list.OrderList(propertyExpression, i => ++i);
public static void OrderList<TModel>(this IList<TModel> list, Expression<Func<TModel, ulong>> propertyExpression) 
    where TModel : notnull
    => list.OrderList(propertyExpression, i => ++i);

public static void OrderList<TModel, TProperty>(
    this IList<TModel> list,
    Func<object?, object?> getMember,
    Action<object?, object?> setMember,
    Func<TProperty, TProperty> increment)

    where TModel: notnull
    where TProperty : struct, IComparable<TProperty>
{
    TProperty order = list.Min(item => (TProperty)getMember(item)!);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        // 'for' (as opposed to 'foreach'),
        // 'object item' (as opposed to 'TModel item'),
        // and list[i] = (TModel)item;
        // are needed, otherwise the method will not work for structs!

        object item = list[i];

        setMember(item, order);
        order = increment(order);

        // .IsValueType is a compile time constant, no checking at runtime occurs
        if (typeof(TModel).IsValueType)
        {
            list[i] = (TModel)item;
        }
    }
}

public static void OrderList<TModel, TProperty>(
    this IList<TModel> list, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertyExpression,
    Func<TProperty, TProperty> increment)

    where TModel : notnull
    where TProperty : struct, IComparable<TProperty>
{
    if(propertyExpression is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyExpression));

    if (propertyExpression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Lambda)
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(propertyExpression)} must be a lambda expression", nameof(propertyExpression));

    if(propertyExpression.Body is not MemberExpression memberExp)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"{nameof(propertyExpression)} must be an expression which accesses (reads) a field or a property", 
            nameof(propertyExpression));
    
    if(propertyExpression.Parameters.Single().Name != (memberExp.Expression as ParameterExpression)?.Name)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $@"{nameof(propertyExpression)} must access a field or a property on the ""{typeof(TModel).Name}"" argument",
            nameof(propertyExpression));
    

    var memberInfo = memberExp.Member;

    if(memberInfo 
        is not FieldInfo
        {
            IsInitOnly: false,
            IsLiteral: false
        }
        and not PropertyInfo
        {
            CanRead: true,
            CanWrite: true
        })
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $@"The field or property {nameof(propertyExpression)} accesses must be readable and writable",
            nameof(propertyExpression));
    }

    Func<object?, object?> getMember;
    Action<object?, object?> setMember;

    if (memberInfo is FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    {
        getMember = fieldInfo.GetValue;
        setMember = fieldInfo.SetValue;
    }
    else if (memberInfo is PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        getMember = propertyInfo.GetValue;
        setMember = propertyInfo.SetValue;
    }
    else throw new NotImplementedException($"{nameof(MemberInfo)} object has an unexpected type {memberInfo.GetType().Name}");

    list.OrderList(getMember, setMember, increment);
}
```

Comment: Looks very nice! That's the kind of thing I was looking for! I'll make sure to try this out thanks a lot! :)